# Is pickling an Rtree spatial index possible?

Tags: python, pickle, r-tree

Pickling Rtree does not appear straightforward as it is a ctypes wrapper. [This comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254781/how-to-save-python-rtree-spatial-index-to-file/254785#comment401778_254781) on SO seconds that assumption.

But, in a (much) older @sgillies [post](https://sgillies.net/2007/10/23/plone-r-tree-spatial-index.html) (the author of this lib), in the comments section, he suggests that it is indeed doable.

Yet, when I recreate these steps locally, the results suggest otherwise:

```
>>> idx = rtree.index.Index()
>>> idx.insert(10, (1,2,3,4))
>>> list(idx.intersection((0,0,5,5)))
# [10]
>>> f = open('foo.p', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(idx, f)
>>> a = pickle.load( open( "foo.p", "rb" ) )
>>> a.get_bounds()
# [1.7976931348623157e+308, 1.7976931348623157e+308, -1.7976931348623157e+308, -1.7976931348623157e+308]]
>>> list(a.intersection((0,0,5,5)))
# []
```

Question:
Is there an operation I am failing to perform correctly to enable pickling of the spatial index? If spatial indexing is possible, what would be the correct way to go about it?

Anecdotally, I was able to pass a GeoPandas.GeoDataFrame.sindex successfully through a pickling process (pickling performed by Dask.distributed). I'm aware it uses cloudpickle or pickle (dep. on situation) but from the GeoPandas side, [`sindex`'s `SpatialIndex` class](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/597dfcf5978c1e45253841cd3ed4ea3a0783a1d8/geopandas/sindex.py) seems to simply be a wrapper around `rtree.index.Index`. I have yet to more deeply dive into understanding why this was the case, but wanted to check here first to see if others had insight.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can write an index to a file, so it should be possible to store it as a string: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254781/saving-python-rtree-spatial-index-to-file/254785

You could also try Dill, which I believe is capable of 'pickling' more kinds of objects, or at least saving the state of the interpreter: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill

Comment: I've tried the Dill, can not serialize the rtree index object's data